# pandas - select and pivot column names into values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Starting with this dataframe df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4],'a':['on','on','off','off'], 'b':['on','off','on','off']})

     a    b  id
0   on   on   1
1   on  off   2
2  off   on   3
3  off  off   4
```

what I would like to achieve is a column `result` with results from the 'on' and 'off' selection of the columns. Expected output is:

```
     a    b  id result
0   on   on   1 [a,b]
1   on  off   2 [a]
2  off   on   3 [b]
3  off  off   4 []
```

so basically I have to select the 'on' values in columns (except `id`) and then keep the resulting column names into lists. My first attemp was using `pivot_table`:

```
d = pd.pivot_table(df, index='id', columns=?, values=?)
```

but I am stuck on how to put the selection into the `values` and the new column into the `columns` args.

Comment: Why not `(df[['a', 'b']] == 'on').apply(lambda x: [x[x].index], axis=1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me works create nested `list`s and then select first value of lists by `str[0]`:

```
df['res'] = df[['a','b']].eq('on').apply(lambda x: [x.index.values[x]], axis=1).str[0]
print (df)
     a    b  id     res
0   on   on   1  [a, b]
1   on  off   2     [a]
2  off   on   3     [b]
3  off  off   4      []
```

Or create tuple first and then cast to `list`s:

```
df['res'] = df[['a','b']].eq('on')
                         .apply(lambda x: tuple(x.index.values[x]), axis=1).apply(list)
print (df)
     a    b  id     res
0   on   on   1  [a, b]
1   on  off   2     [a]
2  off   on   3     [b]
3  off  off   4      []
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of pivot table you can also use

```
df['result'] = df.iloc[:,0:2].eq('on').apply(lambda x: tuple(df.columns[0:2][x]), axis=1)
```

Output :

```
  a    b  id  result
0   on   on   1  (a, b)
1   on  off   2    (a,)
2  off   on   3    (b,)
3  off  off   4      ()
```

Answer (score 1):

or you can using `eq` and `mul`

```
df['res']=(df[['a','b']].eq('on').mul(['a','b'])).values.tolist()

Out[824]: 
     a    b  id     res
0   on   on   1  [a, b]
1   on  off   2   [a, ]
2  off   on   3   [, b]
3  off  off   4    [, ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4],'a':['on','on','off','off'], 'b':['on','off','on','off']})
stringList = []
for i in range(0,df.shape[0]):
    if df['a'][i] == 'on' and df['b'][i] == 'on':
        stringList.append('[a,b]')
    elif df['a'][i] == 'on' and df['b'][i] == 'off':
        stringList.append('[a]')
    elif df['a'][i] == 'off' and df['b'][i] == 'on':
        stringList.append('[b]')
    else:
        stringList.append('[]')
df['result'] = stringList
print df
```

Comment: In pandas its not a good idea to use `for` loop when you can vectorise the solution. Once you get an additional columns of on and off you have to change a lot of code.